# Yii2- Undefined variable: model

Tags: php, model, yii2, undefined

I tried my best to solve this , but I can't seem to figure out where the problem is. Here is my code:

**In action controller**

```
 return $this->render('viewcreated', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
            'id' => $model->id
            /*'searchModel' => $searchModel*/
        ]);
```

**View**

```
$this->title = $model->id; // here it gives the error
```

How can I resolve it ?

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: remove line 'id' => $model->id in controller

Comment: Are you sure that you getting this error in view file?

Answer (score 1):

remove line 'id' => $model->id , as you have not declared $model anywhere and using its value,so its giving error simple.

```
enter code here
```

You can do it as,

```
$model= $this->findModel($id);
return $this->render('viewcreated', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'model' =>$model,
            'id' => $model->id

        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must retrieve the value for  $model outside the render call  so the $model object is available for all the index you accessing in render call

```
$model= $this->findModel($id);
```

Once you have done all the attribute related  to the $model object are available avoiding redeclaration so  you can call render this way

```
return $this->render('viewcreated', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'model' =>$model,
    ]);
```

the value `$model->id` in view should be accessible  directly by the var `$model` passed on index 'model'